# Array of Objects to be used as Synchronization locks being garbage collected

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

Hopefully I'm just making a newbie mistake and someone can point me in the right direction, but here goes:

I need to create a collect or array, some sort of organized group of Objects (or anything else that works) to use as synchronization locks for rendering methods. I have been storing an Object[] as a field, and it seems not to like to store data. Oddly enough, I don't have a problem when I set the lock objects as fields in my class, however if I try to use an array like below, they will return null on lock checks.

First I initialize my lock array:

```
for(int i=0; i<limit*limit; i++) {
    vertexbufferlocks[i]=new Object();}
```

Then I call my rendering function:

```
for(int buf=0; buf<limit*limit; buf++){
    synchronized(bmem.vertexbufferlocks[buf]){
        bindbuffer(vbids[buf]);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, drawlengths[buf]);
}}
```

Which throws: `NullPointerException on bmem.vertexbufferlocks[buf]` on the line `synchronized(bmem.vertexbufferlocks[buf]){` I am definately running the constructor loop first. I tried using a LinkedList, List, and HashMap too, same problem. I am only having problems using this particular type, I have other synchronized classes used for data, initialized and read at the same times, which are not being affected.

New Details:

**THIS** model works fine for me, but causes very small visual hitches since I can't render any data while any other data is being modified, all calls are in the same position as before:

Init:

```
    vertexbufferlock=new Object();
```

Much later after the whole program is initialized:

```
for(int buf=0; buf<limit*limit; buf++){
    synchronized(bmem.vertexbufferlock){
        bindbuffer(vbids[buf]);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, drawlengths[buf]);
}}
```

I think the key problem to address here is that my Objects are probably being garbage collected out of my array once the loop finishes.

Comment: You sure that `bmem.vertexbufferlocks` is the same array as the `vertexbufferlocks` that was initialized?  Maybe that's in another object or something?  Another instance of bmem?

Comment: Also, it is a better pattern to use `vertexbufferlocks.length` instead of `limit*limit`.

Comment: Have you verified that `bmem` is not null?  There are two places that that line could null pointer.  A bit more of your code would be helpful.

Comment: It's definately the right array i'm pointing at. Length is incondusive to the rest of my model, but you're generally right. Bmem is definately not null, as the method being called is called after the bmem constructor in the rest of my code. If this helps you all to think, my program runs fine with a single Object used as a lock (as a bmem field), rather than selecting from an array of Objects based on the piece of the data. What I'm trying to do is have a lock for each piece of my data, so I don't have to freeze rendering during ANY generic data management.

Comment: Why doesn't your initialization code use `bmem.vertexbufferlocks[i]`?

Comment: My initialization code is run by the bmem constructor. My rendering function is within Main, which has bmem as a field, called long after bmem is initialized. Limit only changes outside of runtime (pre-launch config), but all of my arrays are initialized based on limit, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you declare limit final and see if that makes any difference?  Aside from you creating a different vertexbufferlock the GC should not come in and reclaim the elements in the array unless they are Weak/Soft References.  The only alternative explanation is the thread synchronizing on the array occurs before the array is completely initialized.

Comment: Just an idea, but you might have a problem with object publication. Try to use a `AtomicReferenceArray` for holding the lock objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a newbie mistake, I wasn't declaring my limit field before initializing the lock array, however I was previously not using the chunklimit at the point where I declared my single lock (don't need it for one object). It slipped by me because my initialization function is very large. Thanks for the responses regardless! Credit to John Vint for the motivation to double check my limit.